# linker returns undefined reference to 'kernel_main()'?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, linker, operating-system

I like programming, and recently I have been interested in operating systems. So once I found a working tutorial I would start programming, and modifying as much as I knew was possible (at least for me). But there came a time where I realized that programming everything in assembly just wasn't all that great, and I wanted to try programming an operating system in c++ and assembly. Every tutorial out there says it works, but I get one common error when linking: Undefined reference to 'kernel_main', even though the function exists. I tried to see if I spelled it wrong, but I didn't. I also made sure that everything was exactly as it was in the tutorials. Here is the link to an example that didn't work for me:
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/zv07M4Gy/

I have indeed gotten past the compilation. The problem is simply sat within the linking of the two object files. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I am running a 64 bit version of windows 10, so I am using the linker built in to gcc instead of the default windows one. Keep in mind that other tutorials also say to use C as the language for the kernel, and I am also doing that.

EDIT:
For one tutorial, I would use:
`gcc_directory/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe -m elf_i386 -T linker.ld -o main.bin boot.o kernel.o`
For the one linked above, you can find the compilation info in the "How to compile it" section.

EDIT2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmR-_rxWvYc&t=234s

Comment: Show the commands that you use for compiling and linking.

Comment: Make sure you use the proper name mangling. If you use c++ your `kernel_main` will be called something else. You might want to declare it `extern C`. Even then, it may or may not get a leading underscore. Use your tools such as `nm` or `objdump` to see what the actual function name in the object file is.

Comment: I checked using objdump's built in assembly viewer, and it seems that both functions have underscores in front of them. Not really sure if that matters though. (the functions that show text and kernel main)

Comment: The page you refer to uses `g++` and `cpp` file. As I said, that will mangle the name (`_Z11kernel_mainv` on my system). Are you using g++/cpp or not? Was it the `kernel.o` symbol table you checked?

Comment: Yes, I am using g++.

Comment: It seems now that it compiles into the PE format (windows executables). However, a windows executable can't run with that code. Coupled with the fact that it is compiled in a such a way that virtualbox can't execute the code properly (most likely because it is in the wrong format).

Comment: It now seems that it found an undefined reference to 'kernel_main()'